# Gerar uma profissão aleatória para os Jogadores Online

Tags: javascript, array, websocket, socket.io

Eu estou a criar um pequeno jogo (Android) para jogar eu mais uns amigos meus. O jogo chama-se "Polícias e Ladrões". Pelo menos é necessário ter 4 jogadores em que um deles será o POLÍCIA, outro será o CRIMINOSO, outro será a DAMA e os restantes serão CIVÍS (Pessoas Normais).

Eu atualmente tou a usar o Socket.IO para fazer a ligação entre os jogadores e a comunicação. Mas na altura de dar uma profissão para cada jogador, deparei-me com um problema. Esta é a parte do código em que ele cria e envia para o jogador a sua profissão:

```
    var PoliceAlready,CriminalAlready,DamaAlready = false;
    for(var SI in clients) {
        var socket = clients[SI];
        var profissaoT;

        if(!PoliceAlready){
                profissaoT="POLÍCIA";
                PoliceAlready = true;
        }else if(!CriminalAlready){
                profissaoT="CRIMINOSO";
                CriminalAlready = true;
        }else if(!DamaAlready){
                profissaoT="DAMA";
                DamaAlready = true;
        }else{
                profissaoT="CIVÍL";
        }
        socket.emit('profissao', profissaoT);
 }
```

Mas obrigatoriamente terá que ter um Polícia, Criminoso e Dama e estes não se podem repetir. Apartir do código acima ele irá fazer isso mesmo, porém a função for() vai executando os dados do array "clientes" por ordem, o que faz com que sempre tenha a mesma profissão e o objetivo é sempre que voltar a executar esta função de dar a profissão, sempre seja aleatoriamente!

```
var clients = {'/#53h2bn324buh234', '/#h32h324h5234uh2', '/#3pm3b4ij234'};
```

Agradeço desde já quem se disponibilizar a ajudar-me, ou pelo menos tentar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ideal seria explicar a forma que proponho desenhando, mas tentarei ilustrando. Para garantir que cada jogador terá um papel válido e que tenha somente **1 Policial**,  **1 Dama** e **1 Criminoso** vamos imaginar 5 crianças brincando.

Elas pegam uma caixa e colocam 5 papeis escritos as profissões disponíveis, tal que depois que elas terminam a caixa terá *1 Policial*, *1 Criminoso*, *1 Dama* e *2 Cívis*. Elas chacoalham a caixa para embaralhar e então cada uma tira um papel. No final, cada criança saberá a sua profissão e não haverá o risco de não ter saído nenhum policial ou ter dois policiais.

O que fiz nesse código é isso. Existe um *array* chamado papeis, onde possuem números associados a profissões, que são:

**1** = Policial

**2** = Criminoso

**3** = Dama

**4** = Cívil

Caso tenha mais de 4 jogadores, o array é preenchido de cívis, por isso o `push(4)`. Então para cada *cliente* é removido uma profissão aleatóriamente da "caixa".

```js
// deixar os papéis fixos
var papeis = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Clientes em formato de array de objetos, para que cada cliente possua uma profissao
var clients = [{
  'id': '/#53h2bn324buh234',
  'profissao': null
}, {
  'id': '/#h32h324h5234uh2',
  'profissao': null
}, {
  'id': '/#3pm3b4ij234',
  'profissao': null
}, {
  'id': '/#3pm3b4ij222',
  'profissao': null
}];

// Se houver mais de 4 jogadores os demais serão civis
if (clients.length > 4) {
  for (var i = 0; i < clients.length - 4; i++) {
    papeis.push(4);
  }
}

// elegendo o papel para cada jogador
clients.forEach(function(cliente) {
  var aux = Math.floor(Math.random() * papeis.length);
  // splice remove o papel do array de papeis. Isso para
  // para que tenha somente 1 Policia, Dama e Criminoso.
  var papel = papeis.splice(aux, 1);
  cliente.profissao = obterProfissao(papel[0]);
  
  adicionarTela(cliente);
});

function adicionarTela(cliente) {
  var div = document.getElementById("papeis");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = "<span> O jogador: " + cliente.id + " é: <b>" + cliente.profissao + "</b></span><br>"
  div.appendChild(span);
}

function obterProfissao(escolha) {
  //var socket = clients[SI];
  var profissaoT;

  if (escolha == 1) {
    profissaoT = "POLÍCIA";
    PoliceAlready = true;
  } else if (escolha == 2) {
    profissaoT = "CRIMINOSO";
    CriminalAlready = true;
  } else if (escolha == 3) {
    profissaoT = "DAMA";
    DamaAlready = true;
  } else {
    profissaoT = "CIVÍL";
  }
  return profissaoT;
  //socket.emit('profissao', profissaoT);
}
```

```html
<div id="papeis">
</div>
```

PS: Eu adorava esse jogo!

Comment: Lucas, posso ter percebido mal a pergunta e o jogo, mas eu acho que também jogava este jogo :P . Mas assim a alguém que fica a saber as profs de todos, certo? Não deveria ser cada um só saber o seu? De qualquer maneira +1

Comment: Na vida real sim @Miguel! Você diz isso por achar que deveria ser alocado no servidor as profissões?

Comment: Sim, pelo menos pensei que sim. Para não haver conflitos e cada um só saber o seu... Bem logo se vê

Comment: Você está certo. Na verdade exibi no HTML somente para ficar visível a distribuição dos papéis. E fiz no javascript para para monstrar a lógica :) no caso é só passar para o node, ou PHP para ficar mais adequado.

Comment: Funcionou Lucas, fiz os respectivos testes e está exatamente como queria!

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/74c41261bcb64f92bf2e1aa2862ddcec.png

Comment: Que legal cara! Fico feliz por ajudar :)

Comment: Miguel, a profissão escolhida irá ser enviada apenas para esse mesmo jogador com um Socket Emit. O jogo que estou a criar é baseado em Sockets (Socket.IO,NodeJS,...) com um aplicativo Android (Java)!

Answer (score 2):

O que tens de fazer é guardar do lado servidor as profissões que já saíram, neste caso vou escolhendo ao acaso uma das 3 princípais e depois apago a escolhida, quando alguma socket (jogador) sai do jogo essa prof fica de novo à disposição.

Isto é um exemplo funcional dessa funcionalidade, apesar do teu lado cliente ser diferente podes testar isto no browser. Sendo que index.html e server.js estão na mesma pasta.

server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var jogadores = {}; // serve para guardar as sockets e respetiva profissões
var profs = ['POLÍCIA', 'CRIMINOSO', 'DAMA'];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html'); // enviar ficheiro para o browser
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chose_prof', function () {
        if(!(socket.id in jogadores)) {
            var prof = 'CIVIL'; // civil por default
            if(profs.length > 0) { // se ainda existirem as profissões princípais
                prof = profs[Math.floor(Math.random()*profs.length)]; // escolher prof ao acaso
                profs.splice(profs.indexOf(prof), 1); // apagar prof sorteada do nosso array de profs
            }
            jogadores[socket.id] = prof; // guardar socket e prof no obj jogadores, fazer console.log(jogadores); para perceberes
            io.to(socket.id).emit('new_prof', {prof: prof}); // enviar profissão sorteada
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        if(socket.id in jogadores) {
            if(jogadores[socket.id] != 'CIVIL') {
                profs.push(jogadores[socket.id]); // profissão de quem saiu do jogo fica de novo à disposição para outros que entrem
            }
            delete jogadores[socket.id]; // apagar jogador do nosso obj
        }
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<button id="gera_prof">Gerar Prof</button>
<script>
    const socket = io();
    const prof_btn = document.getElementById('gera_prof');
    prof_btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
        socket.emit('chose_prof');
    });
    socket.on('new_prof', function(info){ // receber informação do servidor
        document.body.innerHTML += 'Tu és ' +info.prof;
    });
</script>
```

Comentei o que acho que deve ser esclarecido, caso tenhas duvidas diz.